# MySQL Login and Register

Tags: android, authentication

I'm following the excellent tutorial on Android login and register at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I've implemented the code into my own project but i kept on getting errors. So I decided to try if his code was working and it did just fine. After many hours of searching what was wrong i just decided to copy his code and go from there. But even after just copy-pasting his code into my project I still keep on getting errors.

Here's my logcat error, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very glad.

```
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)                                        
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.example.androidbasic12.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.example.androidbasic12.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:38)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.example.androidbasic12.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 10:12:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

JSONParser.class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) - I think possibly you have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing a network operation in your main UI thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.

You have to use an AsyncTask to get avoid this, by loading the data in its `doInBackground(..)` method.

Comment: I added the class "JSONParser.class" to the questions, is it these kind of operations a should use AsyncTask for? Thanks for pointing out what the problem was though.

Comment: From where are you calling getJSONFromUrl()?

Comment: I'm calling it in the class "UserFunctions", where i have methods such as   ` public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
  // Building Parameters
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
  JSONObject json = jsonParser.JSONParser(loginURL, params);
  // return json
  // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
  return json;
 } `

Comment: Finally figured out how to use it in my application, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This means that networking operations are being done on the UI thread. This is not allowed in android since API 11.

Move the network operations to a background [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

This tutorial might help:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html